# How do I activate a function with a second <button> to call a forEach?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let words = [];
var longestCt = 0;
var longestWord = "";
var myList = [];
var myList = ['Loops','are','used','while','Learning JavaScript'];

function addWords() {
    let template = words.map(word => `<li>${word}</li>`).join('\n');
    document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = template;
}

addWords();

let btnAdd = document.querySelector('button');
let input = document.querySelector('input');


btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    words.push(input.value);
    input.value = '';
    addWords();
});

let findLong = document.querySelector('button');

findLong.addEventListener('click', () => {
   
    let longestCt = 0;
    let longestWord = "";

    words.forEach(function (value) {
        if (value.length > longestCt) {
            longestWord = value;
            longestCt = value.length;
        } else {
            longestWord = longestWord;
        }
    });

    //}
});
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = longestWord;
```

```css
div {
    widows: 20%;
    margin: auto;
}

input, button {
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -40px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_Arr_Input.css">
    <title>Test Longest Array.html</title>

</head>

<body>

<!--Thank you to YouTube KodeBase with my modifications adding a second button which isn't working-->

<div>

    <input type="text">

    <button>Add a Word</button>

    <ul></ul>

    <br>

    <button>Find the Longest</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test_Arr_Input.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Full disclosure; Beginner. With that said; thank you in advance.

I have written a simple JavaScript to return the longest string in an array.
**Here it is as simply a JavaScript function, that I ran from the console,** without interacting with the html:

```
var myList = ['Loops','are','used','while','Learning JavaScript'];

var longestCt = 0;
var longestWord = "";

myList.forEach(function (value) {
    if (value.length > longestCt) {
        longestWord = value; longestCt = value.length;
    } else {
        longestWord = longestWord;
    }
});
console.log(longestWord);
```

I then endeavored to create an HTML page to enter objects into the array and to create a list.
*(Thanks to KodeBase from Youtube for the direction).* The JavaScript for this is posted at the end after the CSS. **Here is the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_Arr_Input.css">
    <title>Test Longest Array.html</title>

</head>

<body>

<!--Thank you to YouTube KodeBase with my modifications adding a second button which isn't working-->

<div>

    <input type="text">

    <button>Add a Word</button>

    <ul></ul>

    <br>

    <button>Find the Longest</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

</div>
  
    <button onclick="intoMyList()">Submit to the array</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <button onclick="findTheLongest()">Find the Longest Word</button>

    <p id="demo2"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test_Arr_Input.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
div {
    widows: 20%;
    margin: auto;
}

input, button {
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -40px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**And here is the final JavaScript:**

```
let words = [];

function addWords() {
    let template = words.map(word => `<li>${word}</li>`).join('\n');
    document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = template;
}

addWords();

let btnAdd = document.querySelector('button');
let input = document.querySelector('input');


btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    words.push(input.value);
    input.value = '';
    addWords();
});

let findLong = document.querySelector('button');

findLong.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //function findTheLongest() {
    let longestCt = 0;
    let longestWord = "";

    myList.forEach(function (value) {
        if (value.length > longestCt) {
            longestWord = value;
            longestCt = value.length;
        } else {
            longestWord = longestWord;
        }
    });

    //}
});
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = longestWord;
```

First I changed a few variable names for more clarity.

But the issue is, although I am able to get the words to enter the array by clicking the first button, the second button does not seem to call the ForEach function to trigger the return of the longest word. I am wondering if I need to somehow differentiate between button 1 and 2 in the HTML. Or if I just need to go back to the drawing board to rethink my understanding of the way I am putting the JS together.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to give each of your buttons a unique ID and then you can use this Id to target the appropriate button in your code.

```
<button id="add-word">Add a Word</button>
```

and

```
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('#add-word');
```

Comment: The addition of the id still allowed the first part, or the array entries, to work but not the forEach.  I also found an incorrect line where I was I had the array name words but in the forEach had myList. I corrected that and reposted.

Comment: Thank you. That helped much after I fixed my own code inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jamiec you should give each button its own unique id and use `getElementById` to target it specifically with that or you can use `onclick="function()"` in the html to call a function from that element directly

The current point of failure also seems to be line 27 reads `myList.forEach` when it should be `words.ForEach`. I've changed a few lines and got a working example here for you: https://jsfiddle.net/z7dsabLc/6/

Comment: Thank you. I had realized myList was wrong and was in the process of fixing when you answered. I compared your code to mine line by line and found 1. where you added the id's in two spots. 2. where you corrected myList. 3. where you moved the final document statement. ( I am still confused by that and parenthesis, braces, semi-colon placement. and 4. the addition of a "console.log("Called")" line. Can you explain that? Just for kicks I commented it out and ran the program and it wasn't necessary so I was wondering if that was a debugging thing you had going on?

Comment: To expand on the answer `querySelect('button')` selects ONLY the first button element. Using console.log was left in from debugging confirming this was only called from one button. Also with the final document statement it was outside of `findLong.addEventListener` so while it found the longest word it didn't update the document correctly.